# How to access usb port with Android 3.0 sdk

Tags: android, usb

I heard that Android 3.0 sdk is having support for USB Host. I want to read / write data on USB port of Android device using android app. This app will send data to a sensor device connected to usb port of android tablet. Is there any sample code or example available for USB read write ?

Comment: I don't know what the story on official support is, but in terms of making it work, a big question would be what type of device and how it communicates (usb-serial if you are lucky).  If there's already support in the linux kernel or userspace drivers for using that usb device with an ordinary desktop linux, you'd be in a better position to make it work.  Then it comes down to a question if the tablet has host-capable hardware, and if you have root access to the device to install new drivers.  Official SDK solutions if there ever are any would probably remove that need.

Answer (score 2):

Try the MissleLauncher example at http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/USB/MissileLauncher/index.html.

Implements very simple async transfer of data.  Clear, concise code.

Answer (score 0):

solution:

1) get access to the USB port

http://atechyblog.blogspot.com/2010/09/reboot-persisting-all-user-access-usb.html

2) get programmatic access so that you can use API's from within Java

http://www.anddev.org/ndk-problems-f56/android-serial-port-usb-t52802.html

http://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/source/checkout

NOTE: you will need root access to make this happen

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to write commercial apps then forget about **rooting**. IOIO library allows you to write to USB port (see [this link](https://github.com/ytai/ioio/wiki)). Although designed to support IOIO board specifically, this lib can be used to send commands through USB.